# Filter folders that do not contain any audio files with bash

Tags: bash, macos

Given a root folder, how do I filter down subfolders that do **not** contain any audio files (mp3, wav and flac)? Do I need to set a variable like

```
folders = find /parentfolder/ -type d
```

and then pass some expression on `${folders}` or is there a one-liner for this?

Comment: It depends what you mean by *"filter down"*. Do you mean you want a list of directories which contain no music or you want a list of directories that do contain music? Then it deoends on what you mean by *"passing an expression"*. Do you want to run a command on those folders? Is it Applescript you want to run or `bash`? What do you actually want to do in simple English please?

Comment: StackOverflow is dedicated to helping solve programming code problems. That is to say, you need to include your best attempt at solving your problem. As is, your Q **may be**  more appropriate for [su]  , but read their help section regarding on-topic questions . AND please read [Help On-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/On-topic) and [Help How-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/How-to-ask) before posting more Qs here.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the subdirectories of `.` (we write that into a file):

```
find . -type d | sort > all_dirs.txt
```

All subdirectories that do contain an mp3 file (goes into another file):

```
find . -name "*.mp3" | xargs dirname | sort | uniq > music_dirs.txt
```

And this is the lines that are only contained in the first file but not the second:

```
diff --new-line-format="" --unchanged-line-format=""  all_dirs.txt music_dirs.txt
```

If you think oneliners are cool and you are working in bash, here it is a bit more condensed:

```
diff --new-line-format="" --unchanged-line-format=""  <(find . -type d | sort) <(find . -name "*.mp3" | xargs dirname | sort | uniq)
```

Comment: You can change the `diff` to `comm -2 -3 all_dirs.txt music_dirs.txt` (only showing unique lines from first file). I think this is shorter. Oh and `sort | uniq` is the same as `sort -u`.

Comment: There is no need for xargs in `find`. Its the same like `find .... -exec dirname {} \;`

Comment: `find . -type d | sort >all_dirs.txt` then
`find . \( -name '*.mp3' -o -name '*.wav' -o -name '*.flac' \) -exec dirname {} \; | sort -u >music_dirs.txt` and then `comm -2 -3 all_dirs.txt music_dirs.txt`